# Rowspan syntax in Markdown

Tags: html, markdown, html-table

I'm trying to create a table in markdown syntax where a cell's content spans across various rows. How can I achieve this?

The table should look something like:

http://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-rowspan-attribute-with-td-element.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here: http://bywordapp.com/markdown/guide.html it says that in markdown the cell content must be in 1 line only.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of today, there is no syntax for tables in standard Markdown language. You can find that within some Markdown extensions like [MultiMarkdown](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown/wiki/MultiMarkdown-Syntax-Guide) or [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/), but no rowspan support.

You can still include html code in your markdown like [in this example](https://gist.github.com/benweet/4dc0af6bf4fa931ede6f):

```
**Hello**
<table>
<tr><td>rowspan1</td><td rowspan="2">rowspan2</td></tr>
<tr><td>rowspan1</td></tr>
</table>
*World*
```

Comment: And that's the other reason why link content should best be summarized in a response... that "example" link is (probably long) gone now :(

Comment: @Christian it's been a few years but I've found and added that missing example content

Comment: @RobinJamesKerrison A bit too late for my use case but in the name of everyone reading this in the future: thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

I think I'm a little late, but you can't take it so narrowly.
Actually was able to do tricks like this with Joplin using the plugin "MultiMarkdown", because you can use normal HTML markup within the table cells :

```markdown
|
|1<td rowspan="2">3</td>
|2 
|4|5|
```

This is a pretty nasty mix of Markdown and HTML which I'm pretty sure will make some people frown. What results in something like this :

[image: fig.1 using MultiMarkdown]

What is very important is that Multimarkdown is not the one that allows this mixture of Markdown and HTML, no it also works with normal Markdown 2.0.

Multimarkdown is actually a table plugin that allows me to omit the header and the extra two cells on the right side.

The closest to what the OP requested, and what I think can be created with vanilla Markdown 2.0 (without MultiMarkdown) would look like this:

```markdown
|A |B
|--|--
|1<td rowspan="2">3</td>|2
|4|5
|6|7
```

[image: fig.2 using vanilla Markdown2.0]

Comment: What about rowspan in the first cell of row?

Comment: What I did is, instead of using rowspan at all, I just kept one cell but used `<br />` to set the next item underneath the first

Comment: @Rinor That defeats the purpose of rows in a table. While it works, it creates another issue in that you have multiple rows stuffed into one row. At least in my case, if I want to have Latex in a table in Wiki.js I have to use Markdown as for some reason it doesn't want to render inline equations using HTML tables.